# Какой подход лучше при создание панель управления сайта на Angular 4?

Tags: vue.js, администрирование, angular4, админка

Здравствуйте! Хотел сделать панель управления сайта на джаваскрипт фреймворке ангулар 4, но джаваскрипт фреймворки я использую в первый раз
Поэтому не знаю какой подход лучше
Бекенд в Yii2, база MySQL, с АПИом отлично справлюсь. Осталось только реализовать работа с ангуларом(авторизация регистрация, права доступа, добавления и удаления контенты и т.д) и админка должна быть мультиязычной
Что посоветуете?
Есть пример какой нибудь проекта? и вообще с чего начать? 
В проекте достаточно большая структура, функциональности...

> и ещё вопрос(просто советь нужен) - есть вариант сделать этот админку на Vuejs 2. для таких проектах лучше выбрать ангулар или вю?

**за ранее спасибо и извиняюсь если чего-то не то написал)**

Answer (score 1):

Для мультиязычности: ngx-translate
Для авторизация регистрация, права доступа, добавления и удаления контенты: прочитайте про REST.
C чего начать: https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit, но я бы посоветовал создовать проект c angular-cli

Vue vs Angular: https://habrahabr.ru/post/338068/
Мой выбор пал на ангулар но это дело вкуса!